# Concurrency of lines made with end points of concurrent lines of a triangle made by end point of concurrent lines and points of given triangle.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles

In $\triangle ABC$, $AD, BE$ and $CF$ are concurrent lines. $P, Q, R$ are points on $EF, FD, DE$ such that $DP, EQ$ and $FR$ are concurrent. Prove that $AP, BQ,$ and $CR$ are also concurrent.

(To be done with Menelaus theorem, Ceva's theorem, Stewart's theorem and elementary geometry)

Source:CTPCM

I am unable to first of all draw a good figure but with my rough figure I tried using Ceva's Theorem and then linking it with areas. But I was just getting stuck so I want some kind of hint and drawing to visualize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof from EGMO, as this is quite well known as Cevian Nest.

Proof : Swap $D,E,F$ with $X,Y,Z$ and $P,Q,R$ with $D,F,E$ for convenience.

By sine rule, $\frac{\sin BAD}{\sin CAD}=\frac{\frac{ZD}{ZA}\sin ADZ}{\frac{YD}{YA}\sin ADY}=\frac{ZD}{YD}\frac{YA}{ZA}$, use trigonometric form of Ceva now to get that it is enough to prove $\frac{ZD×YA×XE×ZB×YF×XC}{YD×ZA×ZE×XB×XF×YC}=1$, which follows from Ceva's Theorem on $\Delta XYZ$ and $\Delta ABC$

Comment: What was so inconvenient about the OP's point-labels that you had to change six of them?

Comment: This proof is from the book EGMO by Evan Chen, and as the notations in that diagram involved $X,Y,Z$ hence i also changed that